# How to convert table with merged cells to responsive design?

Tags: html, css, html-table, fluid-layout

I need to display data on desktop screens in a table as shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3LgL9z1/).

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l.tg-left{width:22%}
.tg .tg-yw4l.tg-center{width:35%}
.tg .tg-yw4l.tg-right{width:35%}
.tg .tg-yw4l.tg-exleft{width:30%}
.tg .tg-yw4l.tg-excenter{width:50%}
.tg .tg-yw4l.tg-exright{width:20%}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l tg-left" rowspan="2"><img src="http://dev.guitar-dreams.com/images/TAB.gif"</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l tg-center">Title of Guitar Lesson</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l tg-right">Category</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2">Here is the description. If there is a lot of text here, then this cell's bottom edge should simply drop down, and the cell wit the image should corre ponsingly have its bottom edge drop down.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3">
        <table class="tg" width=100%> 
           <tr>
              <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="3">Exercises in this lesson</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="tg-yw4l tg-exleft">Exercise Title</td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l tg-excenter">Here is an exercise description. If the text is long, this cell's bottom edge should expand downward, along with other cells in this row.</td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l tg-exright">Media: Audio, Video</td>
          </tr>

        </table>              
    </td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

When viewed on mobile devices, I would like for all cells to be stacked vertically, so you would have

```
Lesson Image
Lesson Title
Lesson Category
Lesson Description
Exercises in Lesson
Exercise Title
Exercise Description
Exercise Media
```

Any idea how I would either 1) implement this as a table that would have the behavior I described or 2) implement as divs that would mimic a table with the behaviors described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a media query to your styles to display table cells as block elements at smaller screen sizes.

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
    table.tg tr td { 
        display:block;
        width:auto !important;
        padding:0 0 5px; 
        border:0;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/80xy7rLo/

Comment: Wow - I never would have thought it would be that simple! Thanks!